# Is there any way to define a variable from a formula depending on what variables are given?

Tags: matlab

Imagine you have the following formula:

```matlab
a=4*b*c^2
```

Is there any way in Matlab to program this is in  a way that the if 2 of 3 variables are provided, Matlab will solve and provide the missing one?

Because the only alternative I am seeing is using switch-case and solving the equation myself.

```matlab
if isempty(a)
switchVar=1
elseif isempty(b)
switchVar=2;
else
switchVar=3;
end

switch switchVar
case 1
a=4*b*c^2;
case 2
b=a/4/c^2;
case 3
c=sqrt(a/4/b);
end
```

Thanky you very much in advance!

Comment: Shooting from the hip here: you can try reducing your equation to be equal to zero (`0 = 4*b*c^2-a`) and using a symbolic/numeric solver on it (e.g. `fsolve()`), which will spit out the missing variable.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea, I will try it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*For a numeric (rather than symbolic) solution...*

You can do this with some faffing around and anonymous functions. See the comments for details:

```
% For the target function: 0 = 4*b*c - a
% Let x = [a,b,c]

% Define the values we know about, i.e. not "c"
% You could put any values in for the known variables, and NaN for the unknown.
x0 = [5, 10, NaN];

% Define an index for the unknown, and then clear any NaNs
idx = isnan(x0);
x0(idx) = 0;

% Make sure we have 1 unknown
assert( nnz( idx ) == 1 );

% Define a function which handles which elements of "x" 
% actually influence the equation
X = @(x,ii) ( x*idx(ii) + x0(ii)*(~idx(ii)) );

% Define the function to solve, 0 = 4*b*c - a = 4*x(2)*x(3)^2 - x(1) = ...
f = @(x) 4 * X(x,2) * X(x,3).^2 - X(x,1);

% Solve using fzero. Note this requires an initial guess
x0(idx) = fzero( f, 1 );
```

We can check these results are correct by plotting the function for a range of `c` values, and checking the intersection with the x-axis aligns to the output `x0(3)`:

```
c = -1:0.01:1;
y = 4*x(2)*c.^2-x(1);
figure
hold on
plot(t,y);
plot(t,y.*0,'r');
plot(x0(3),0,'ok','markersize',10,'linewidth',2)
```

[image: plot]

Note that there were 2 valid solutions, since this is a quadratic. The initial condition provided to `fzero` will largely dictate which solution is found.

---

**Edit:**

You can condense this down a bit with some tweaks to my earlier syntax:

```
% Define all initial conditions. This includes known variable values
% i.e. a = 5, b = 10
% As well as the initial guess for unknown variable values
% i.e. c = 1 (maybe? ish?)
x0 = [5, 10, 1];
% Specify the index of the unknown variable in x
idx = 3;
% Define the helper function which handles the influence of each variable
X = @(x,ii) x*(ii==idx) + x0(ii)*(ii~=idx);
% Define the function to solve, as before
f = @(x) 4 * X(x,2) * X(x,3).^2 - X(x,1);
% Solve
x0(idx) = fzero( f, x0(idx) )
```

This approach has the benefit that you can just change `idx` (and re-run the definition steps for `X` and `f`) to switch the variable of choice!

Answer (score 2):

- First, specify the given known variables
- Then rewrite the equation as  `0 = 4*b*c - a`
- Finally use `solve` to find the missing value

Code is as follows

```
syms a b c
% define known variable
a = 2; c = 5;
% equation  rewritten 
f = 4*b*c^2 - a == 0;
missing_value = solve(f);
```